# Merge default options containing object with JSON Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I need to merge these two objects to get below output using JS. Thanks in advance and its ok to use jquery library if needed

```js
var defaultOptions = {
        count:3
    };
    
    var JSON = {
      one:{
        title:"something",
        count:15
      },
      two:{
        title:"another"
      }
    }
    
    // expecting
    
    var JSON = {
      one:{
        title:"something",
        count:15
      },
      two:{
        title:"another",
        count:3
      }
    }
```

Comment: I don't need to iterate the whole object to accomplished this task

Comment: ok, so what do you want

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: @JaromandaX I need to get the expected out ( with the default value ), Originally there is no count value in "two" object.

Comment: @Dhanan please checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can use   `for..in` loop to check if object has `"count"` property, if false, set `"count"` property of default object to object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$.extend` to merge objects.

```
    for (var key in JSON) {
       if (!JSON[key]['count']){
          $.extend(JSON[key], defaultOptions);
       }
    }
```

Update: Loop through the object and check for `count` object

Comment: I Can't because there is some other nodes

Comment: Updated post and placed a loop for checking count

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var defaultOptions = {
        count:3
    };
    
    var someObject = {
      one:{
        title:"something",
        count:15
      },
      two:{
        title:"another"
      }
    }
    
   for (var property in someObject) {
    if (someObject[property].count == undefined) {
       console.log(someObject[property]);
       someObject[property].count = defaultOptions.count;
       console.log(someObject[property]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also use `in` operator at `if` condition `for (var prop in JSON) {
  if (!("count" in JSON[prop])) JSON[prop]["count"] = defaultOptions["count"]
}`

Answer (score 0):

It's like this:

```js
function mergeObjs(){
  var a = [].slice.call(arguments), o = a.shift();
  for(var i=0,l=a.length; i<l; i++){
    for(var p in a[i]){
      o[p] = a[i][p];
    }
  }
  return o;
}
console.log(mergeObjs({neat:'totally'}, {cool:'works', someAry:[1,7,5,'test']}, {what:'now', really:7}));
```